# Strange icon near every shortcut on desktop

Tags: windows

This icon came from nowhere, what does it mean? (win10)

[image]

Comment: It means that you have somehow ticked the share-folder checkbox on your desktop or any parent folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sharing icon, it means that the file or shortcut has had it's share option ticked in it's properties, making it work for sharing between users or over the network. To remove the icon, you can just untick the share checkbox in the properties. You may be able to select multiple -> right click -> properties -> untick the sharing box, which will be on one of the tabs. (I don't have a windows machine handy)

If your whole desktop folder is set to share, you could just uncheck that.